# Derived Class Properties Getting Passed to SQL Server via Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity, derived

When retrieving a list of objects from SQL Server , I am getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Invalid column name 'AccountName'
>   Invalid column name 'AccountNumber'

I understand that the database does not contain those columns, but I don't believe my code should be passing those columns for retrieval.

I have a class that is being derived from and Entity Framework code-first class that has a few extra properties added to it.

For some reason, when I make the database call, it passes the extra properties created by the `TransactionHistoryGrid` class to SQL Server, when it should only be passing the `TransactionHistory` properties.

Here is the code:

Entity Framework code-first class:

```
public partial class TransactionHistory : Transaction
{
    public string BillingAddressCity { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressCompany { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressCountry { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressFax { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressFirst { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressLast { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressPhone { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressState { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressStreet { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressZip { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Class to populate Kendo Grid:

```
public class TransactionHistoryGrid : TransactionHistory
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public static List<TransactionHistoryGrid> GetTransactionHistoryGrid()
    {
        List<TransactionHistoryGrid> grids = new List<TransactionHistoryGrid>();

        // This is where the trouble begins:
        foreach (TransactionHistory t in GetAllTransactionHistories())
        {
            // It doesn't make it this far.
            var grid = new TransactionHistoryGrid()
            {
                Account = t.Account;
                AccountName = t.Account.AccountName;
                AccountNumber = t.Account.AccountNumber;
            };
            grids.Add(grid);
        }
        return grids;
    }
}
```

Method to retrieve data:

```
    public static List<TransactionHistory> GetAllTransactionHistories()
    {
        using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            // Error gets thrown here... Why are the extra properties being read??
            return context.Set<TransactionHistory>().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Usage from controller:

```
public ActionResult TransactionHistory_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request = null)
{
    List<TransactionHistoryGrid> transactionHistory = TransactionHistoryGrid.GetTransactionHistoryGrid();            

    DataSourceResult result = transactionHistory.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thoughts? Suggestions?

This is what SQL Server Profiler returns:

(`AccountName`, `AccountNumber`, and `TransactionHistoryGrid` should never be sent to SQL. Why is it?)

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
    ...
    [Extent1].[AccountName] AS [AccountName], 
    [Extent1].[AccountNumber] AS [AccountNumber], 
    [Extent1].[Account_ID] AS [Account_ID], 
    [Extent1].[BillingStatement_ID] AS [BillingStatement_ID]
    FROM [dbo].[TransactionHistories] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'TransactionHistoryGrid',N'TransactionHistory')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting from the comment thread:

Type Discovery as described **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)** is probably at play. The **[[NotMapped]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** attribute
has the AttributeTargets.Class, AttributeTargets.Property and AttributeTargets.Field flags, so unless you ever intend to manipulate the TransactionHistoryGrid properties directly via the DatabaseContext, you could just put the attribute on the entire class.

```
[NotMapped]
public class TransactionHistoryGrid : TransactionHistory
{
    ...
}
```

The alternative would be to move the TransactionHistoryGrid class into another assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If these are your EF models and the property is not part of the database structure you should be annotating the properties with the **[NotMapped]** Attribute so that the sql generation does not pick up the property and try to add it into the select statement.

Hopefully this site should help with explaining the annotations. 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx

I personally prefer to transform my database models into view models. This way I can ensure any non-database properties can be managed outside of the "data gathering layer" section of my project.

I am not an EF person as I prefer to use Telerik's DataAccess as my ORM solution.

Comment: Account is actually part of the table columns. I have left out some of the code for the purpose of posting on here.
I am using [NotMapped] on other properties and it works fine.
When making a direct call to the GetAllTransactionHistories() method, everything works fine, but when I try to make that call in the TransactionHistoryGrid class (Derived from TransactionHistory class), that is when it throws the error.
For some reason it is passing the "added" properties of the class being derived from the enityt framework partial class, but I don't understand how or why it is doing that.

Comment: If I cannot get this to work the way I have it set up, I will resort to returning the data via view model, but I'm just very curious as to why this isn't working.
Thanks for the response.

Comment: Looking closer at the code you highlight the issue is being thrown when you try to retrieve the collection of transaction histories. This looks like it derives from Transaction so what is in this class? Do you have these properties here as well? Also what happens if you run a profiler against the sql that is being generated either through SSMS or Visual Studio (if you have the intellitrace option)

Comment: Transaction (AuthorizeNet class) has a bout 30 properties that I did not want to recreate, so in the Enity Framework partial class, I inherited from Transaction class so that Entity Code First would do all the work for me. I also add a few extra properties to it.
That works just fine. Everything works just fine until I try to use the TransactionHistoryGrid class with added properties.

I will update my code to reflect the TransactionHistory class.
Also will run profile and see what SQL is saying

Comment: See JimmySweets comments below. Turns out the properties are attempting to be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance. I'd say the issue has to be getting caused by the Account entity. Not the Transaction or the TransactionHistory. Try getting a DbSet of Accounts and see if you get the same error. If you don't then check whether you have Lazy Loading set on the context or try explicity including the Accounts.

I should add that if you are not able to get the Accounts back (having the AccountName and AccountNumber) then you need to double check the EDMX model for the accounts and compare it with the actual data store you're accessing. Those two are probably out of sync in that case, and considering your model still thinks AccountName and AccountNumber are in there, I would say it's on the data store side.

1) Make sure the actual data store has the AccountName and AccountNumber fields in the Accounts table.

2) Make sure Account entity in your EDMX is mapped to SAME Accounts table.

3) Make sure the Account entity properties for AccountName and AccountNumber are mapped to the SAME AccountName and AccountNumber fields.

I only mention this as a possibility because I've run into this before when switching environments from DEV to STAGING. The data stores are different, but EDMX doesn't know it.

Comment: The Account entity isn't the issue. Any property that I add to the TransactionHistoryGrid class gets passed to the GetAllTransactionHistories() method, thus throwing the error because SQL cannot find the columns.

Comment: TransactionHistory.Account comes back just fine, as does it's properties.
But when TransactionHistoryGrid (Derived from TransactionHistory) has any properties added to it, those properties some how get passed to the GetAllTransactionHistories() method, thus resulting in the SQL error because those columns do not exist in SQL.

Comment: Here's my thinking: TransactionHistoryGrid shouldn't be in play at all because of the way you've encapsulated the call within it's own method. You're not actually doing any direct casting or using it as a type parameter in the context.So there are only three entities in play here, the Transaction, TransactionHistory and the Account. Is it possible that Transaction has AccountName and AccountNumber still left over in the model.

Comment: Take Account out of the equation. If I created a property: public string StackOverFlowRocks {get;set;}
The error would then say that SQL couldn't find column StackOverFlowRocks

Comment: AccountName and AccountNumber are only located in TransactionHistoryGrid

Comment: Ok, there is another possibility. Type discovery could be at play here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: Putting [NotMapped] directly on the TransactionHistoryGrid class may be your best option. Or moving TransactionHistoryGrid to a different assembly.

Comment: The attribute is allowed on Classes, Properties and Fields, so unless you ever intend to manipulate the TransactionHistoryGrid properties directly via the DataContext, you could just put the attribute on the entire class.

Comment: That did the trick. Now I have to reconsider my structure. Though adding the [NotMapped] works, I never intended for those properties to be seen in that context.